# Could a mute person become a police officer in a small town?

Tags: internal-consistency, law-enforcement

Obviously one would expect there to be barriers to becoming a police officer for a mute, deaf, or deaf-mute person when a job such as that sometimes requires quick and concise communication between officers or officers and civilians/suspects. It's only natural. But could a person who's mute or who has difficulty with speech living in today's day and age overcome these difficulties sufficiently enough that a small town could be convinced to hire them as a police officer? What about a park ranger?

Potential solutions I can think of would be using a speech-generating device or a database of pre-recorded messages that you would expect to use often on the job, or having a partner who does the talking for you. These probably wouldn't work in a more metropolitan police department, but in a relatively quiet small town area, could any of these work well enough to be solutions? Or is there still no good reason to hire a mute person for a job like this?

Answer (score 1):

No. And yes.

Would they be able to be a field officer? Absolutely not. You can't be fumbling around with a speech generating device or prerecorded messages while you're doing anything else, or mistakes happen and people die.

Could they be a "Police Officer" that works in the station? Sure. Not a dispatcher for obvious reasons, but there are plenty of other jobs they could do without needing urgent communication.